# JPA How to apply filter to EJB criteriaquery

Tags: java, jpa, filter

How do I get only, the entities from given user

```
public List<T> findRangeByUser(int[] range, User user) {
    javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder cb = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();
    javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
    Predicate condition = cb.equal(cq.from(User.class), user);
    cq.select(cq.from(entityClass));
    cq.where(condition);
    javax.persistence.Query q = getEntityManager().createQuery(cq);
    q.setMaxResults(range[1] - range[0]);
    q.setFirstResult(range[0]);
    return q.getResultList();
}
```

How should I approch this? Please also note that the user is a foreign key refering to the userId in the User table
currently is returning all items
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public List<T> findRangeByUser(int[] range, User user) {
    javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder cb = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();
    javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
    javax.persistence.criteria.Root<T> rt = cq.from(entityClass);     
    cq.where(cb.equal(rt.get("useridUser"), user));
    javax.persistence.Query q = getEntityManager().createQuery(cq);
    q.setMaxResults(range[1] - range[0]);
    q.setFirstResult(range[0]);
    return q.getResultList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The criteria builder needs a condition that evaluates the user ID to the returned result. Something like this:

```
Predicate condition = qb.equal(root.get(field), usuerController.getUserSession().getUser().getIdUser());
critera.where(condition);
```

Replace the "field" with the SingularAttribute that references the User Id.

Comment: @NeerajKrisna Thanks I have tried this but I'm getting an EJB exception, unkown source, I also updated the query